# adding more options to DataTables

Tags: datatables

I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [[6, 'asc']]
        })
        .columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ 
                {
                    type: "select",
                    values: [
                        'La Noscea',
                        'Black Shroud',
                        'Thanalan',
                        'Coerthas',
                        'Mor Dhona'
                    ]  
                },
                {
                    type: "select",
                    values: [
                        'Western La Noscea',
                        'Middle La Noscea',
                        'Eastern La Noscea',
                        'Lower La Noscea',
                        'Upper La Noscea',
                        'Outer La Noscea',
                        'Eastern Shroud',
                        'South Shroud',
                        'Central Shroud',
                        'North Shroud',
                        'Western Thanalan',
                        'Eastern Thanalan',
                        'Southern Thanalan',
                        'Northern Thanalan',
                        'Central Thanalan',
                        'Coerthas Central Highlands',
                        'Mor Dhona'
                    ]  
                },
                { type: "text" },
                { type: "select", values: [ 'S', 'A', 'B']  }
            ],
        });
    });
</script>
```

and I want to add this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
    });

    $("div.toolbar").html('<b>Custom tool bar! Text/images etc.</b>');
} );
```

I tried like a 100 different ways, can someone plz assist me and maybe also tell me what i should look for if i want to add more things?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [[6, 'asc']],
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
        })
        .columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ 
                {
                    type: "select",
                    values: [
                        'La Noscea',
                        'Black Shroud',
                        'Thanalan',
                        'Coerthas',
                        'Mor Dhona'
                    ]  
                },
                {
                    type: "select",
                    values: [
                        'Western La Noscea',
                        'Middle La Noscea',
                        'Eastern La Noscea',
                        'Lower La Noscea',
                        'Upper La Noscea',
                        'Outer La Noscea',
                        'Eastern Shroud',
                        'South Shroud',
                        'Central Shroud',
                        'North Shroud',
                        'Western Thanalan',
                        'Eastern Thanalan',
                        'Southern Thanalan',
                        'Northern Thanalan',
                        'Central Thanalan',
                        'Coerthas Central Highlands',
                        'Mor Dhona'
                    ]  
                },
                { type: "text" },
                { type: "select", values: [ 'S', 'A', 'B']  }
            ],
        });

        $("div.toolbar").html('<b>Custom tool bar! Text/images etc.</b>');
    });
</script>
```